# File not found when trying to import a header file into the bridging header?

Tags: swift, frameworks, xcode6

I'm trying to import my speech recognition framework into my project. Sadly my project is in Swift and speech rec is in objc. I don't see a problem with this. I have created a bridging header file before importing the framework and compiled to make sure it has no errors. Then I dragged the framework into my project. Got a successful compile again. Now I type this in my header file:

```
#ifndef Bridging_Header_h
#define Bridging_Header_h

#import "SpeechKit/SpeechKit.h"

#endif
```

And then I get the error: `"SpeechKit/SpeechKit.h" file not found`
I have tried reimporting the framework. Deleting and making a new header file etc. Nothing seems to work. I don't get why it's not picking up the header files from the framework.

Does anyone have any ideas? All help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you try  `#import "SpeechKit.h"`?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Yes, sadly that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: You found any solution brother???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `#import <SpeechKit/SpeechKit.h>` in bridging header and don't forget to place `import SpeechKit` in your swift file

Comment: Brother I do same as you suggested.
But when I used 

import SpeechKit   in my appDelegate.Swift

a red line appeared on SpeechKit. any way I imported it.
But after it, i am unable to access any of its class.
Like SpeechKit etc.

Comment: @AabanTariqMurtaza Honestly it's been so long and I don't have the code anymore. But I did get it to work. Instead of dragging in the framework, I had to do file->import or something. I've also didn't include '<>' in the import. Also make sure that you add the import Speechkit inside the switch file as well. I think I even created a new project because xcode was giving me problems and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Try `#import "SpeechKit.h"` or `#import <SpeechKit/SpeechKit.h>` instead `#import "SpeechKit/SpeechKit.h"`

Comment: Sadly I get the same issue. Would the problem might be the way I imported the framework? I just dragged the framework into my project. Maybe you have to do file add file to project or something?

Comment: Are you using cocoapods?